# Is it possible to use EL for sessionScoped bean without creating a new session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, el

Basically, I want a jsp page that is only accessible to clients that have an existing session and do not create a new session for those who access the page directly with <%@ page session="false">. The existing session will have a bean set as a session attribute and I want to access this beans properties with EL.

Comment: where is this existing session going to come from?

Comment: a login servlet that will authenticate the user and set the bean

Comment: so if the value is not set then redirect to the login page

Comment: yes correct. I was wondering if it is possible to use EL even if I set <%@ page session = "false" %> at the top of the page.

Comment: Login doesn't change the session. It just authenticates it.

Comment: `<%@ page session = "false" %>` - why do you want to do that?

Comment: Isn't creating a new unnecessary session for those who directly access the page a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

The approach <%@ page session="false"> is wrong. Instead, I should let a jsp session be created and check with session.isNew and redirect those who access the page directly.